# How to use daply (from plyr) on 2billion rows using less memory

Tags: r, memory, plyr

Does any one know, how one could apply the following function that converts 3 columns table into a matrix using a file that has 2 billion rows (with less than 10GB memory).

> where x is 1st, y is 2nd and z is 3rd column.

```
library(plyr)
daply(a, .(x, y), function(x) x$z)
```

Comment: do you have enough memory to read the table before running daply?

Comment: Good question and the answer is no. I used 15 GB and it throws Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.6 Gb

Comment: what size is the file on your computer? And what do you want to do with the matrix? A model? Unless this function is well justified, and you are able to exploit the result, I would not do something like that. Among the alternatives: use `fread` from the data.table package, take a sample to do your analysis.

Comment: 60 GB is the file size. I want to apply a clustering method using the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot load all the tuples at once

I know this is not the answer you are looking for: use SQLite.

The problem with R is that it must load the entire frame at once. If you don't have enough memory, then it simply can't continue.

SQLite is way smarter than R to do aggregates. Perhaps the most important feature is that it optimizes the memory available, and if it can, it does not need to read all the elements at once. See this for details on how to do it.

http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-sqlite-in-r/

If SQLite does not support the aggregate you want, you can create it yourself (see user defined functions in SQLite).

Alternatively you can try to partition your data (outside R), so you can aggregate in stages. But that will still require some sort of program that can read process the files in less than the available memory. Unix/MacOS/Linux sort is one of those utilities that can deal with more-than-available-memory data. It might be useful.

Comment: I will try it. thanks. However for now, I am splitting the files into 5 equal chunks and running successfully.